# Arranging json to match another json template

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I am receiving the 1st JSON and I want to change its structure so that it will match my 2nd JSON template

Here's the JSON [link](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceeINjWZvm?indent=2) and I want to format it into [this](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceuBuGMYPm?indent=2)

And here's what I've done so far:

```
for(i=0;i<json.option.length;i++)
{
    var row=json.option[i];

    if(!option.includes(row.option.option_id))
    {
        option.push({
            option_id:row.option.option_id,
            option_name:row.option.option_name,
            max:row.option.max,
            min:row.option.min,
            value:row.option.value,
            price:row.option.price
        })
    }


    if(!option_group.includes(row.option_group_id))
    {
        option_group.push({
            option_group_id:row.option_group_id,
            option_group_name:row.option_group_name,
            max:row.max,
            min:row.min,
            option:option
        })
    }
}
```

And the problem occurs when the 1st JSON *option.option_group_id* already exist in the array, it will not add any object anymore. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: your second link is broken.

Comment: There is no `Whipped Cream` in the input, how does it come to the output? Also, how is `quantity_max` calculated?

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a solution that uses Ramda.js

```js
const data =  {
    item_id: 1065,
    item_name: "Drink",
    item_price: 1,
    option: [
        {
            max: 1,
            min: 1,
            option: {
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                option_id: 3426,
                option_name: "Small",
                price: 0,
                value: 1
            },
            option_group_id: "drink_size",
            option_group_name: "Size"
        },
        {
            max: 1,
            min: 1,
            option: {
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                option_id: 3426,
                option_name: "Medium",
                price: 0,
                value: 1
            },
            option_group_id: "drink_size",
            option_group_name: "Size"
        },
        {
            max: 1,
            min: 1,
            option: {
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                option_id: 3426,
                option_name: "Large",
                price: 0,
                value: 1
            },
            option_group_id: "drink_size",
            option_group_name: "Size"
        },
        {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            option: {
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                option_id: 3580,
                option_name: "Decaf",
                price: 0,
                value: 1
            },
            option_group_id: "coffee_extras",
            option_group_name: "Extras"
        },
        {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            option: {
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                option_id: 3581,
                option_name: "Espresso Shot",
                price: 30,
                value: 1
            },
            option_group_id: "coffee_extras",
            option_group_name: "Extras"
        }
    ],
    quantity_value: 1
}


const transformGroup = (group) =>
  R.pipe(
    R.mergeAll,
    R.assoc("option", R.pluck("option", group))
  )(group)
  
const transformOption = (option) => 
  R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(R.prop("option_group_id")),
    R.map(transformGroup),
    R.values,
  )(option)

const transformData = (data) => 
  R.pipe(
    R.assoc("option_group", transformOption(data.option)),
    R.dissoc("option"),
  )(data)

console.log(transformData(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some incongruences between the given input and the output:

- Option name "Whipped Cream" is missing in the input object.
- There is no explanation about how `qty`, `qty_min` and `qty_max` should be altered / calculated.

Below is a solution using `array.reduce`, `array.map`, `Set` and `Object.assign`. Further explanations can be found below in the code.

The output json structure is actually correct, `qty` and `qty_max` should be calculated according to the desired criteria, which is currently not explained.

```js
const input = {
  "item_name": "Drink", 
  "item_id": 1065, 
  "quantity_value": 1, 
  "item_price": 1, 
  "option": [
    {
      "max": 1, 
      "option": {
        "min": 0, 
        "option_name": "Small", 
        "max": 1, 
        "price": 0, 
        "option_id": 3426, 
        "value": 1
      }, 
      "option_group_name": "Size", 
      "option_group_id": "drink_size", 
      "min": 1
    }, 
    {
      "max": 1, 
      "option": {
        "min": 0, 
        "option_name": "Medium", 
        "max": 1, 
        "price": 0, 
        "option_id": 3426, 
        "value": 1
      }, 
      "option_group_name": "Size", 
      "option_group_id": "drink_size", 
      "min": 1
    }, 
    {
      "max": 1, 
      "option": {
        "min": 0, 
        "option_name": "Large", 
        "max": 1, 
        "price": 0, 
        "option_id": 3426, 
        "value": 1
      }, 
      "option_group_name": "Size", 
      "option_group_id": "drink_size", 
      "min": 1
    }, 
    {
      "max": 5, 
      "option": {
        "min": 0, 
        "option_name": "Decaf", 
        "max": 1, 
        "price": 0, 
        "option_id": 3580, 
        "value": 1
      }, 
      "option_group_name": "Extras", 
      "option_group_id": "coffee_extras", 
      "min": 0
    }, 
    {
      "max": 5, 
      "option": {
        "min": 0, 
        "option_name": "Espresso Shot", 
        "max": 1, 
        "price": 30, 
        "option_id": 3581, 
        "value": 1
      }, 
      "option_group_name": "Extras", 
      "option_group_id": "coffee_extras", 
      "min": 0
    }
  ]
};

// Accumulator for the outer max quantity. Assuming it's the sum of all the inner "max" quantities.
let maxQty = 0;
let _groupedOptions = [...new Set(input.option.map(o => o.option_group_id))].reduce((acc, next) => {
  // Acquire the (outer) option for the [next] item, where next is the option_group_id.
  const _filteredOptions = input.option.filter(o => o.option_group_id === next);
  // Max qty of the following options. Assuming it's the sum of the inner quantities. Otherwise, change that.
  let innerMaxQty = _filteredOptions.map(i => +i.max).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  // Eventual update of the outer max quantity. Eventually change this if the calculation criteria is different.
  maxQty = maxQty < innerMaxQty ? innerMaxQty : maxQty;
  // Acquire the inner options of the looped item.
  const _innerOptions = _filteredOptions.map(o => o.option);
  // Push a new object containing the desired options in the inner option property, by getting the defualt object informations from the outer option group.
  // As a side note, you should not get the _filteredOptions[0], but you should give further explanations about how the master object should calculated the properties, otherwise it's quite vague.
  // After pushing, return the accumulator for the next iteration.
  return acc.push(Object.assign(_filteredOptions[0], {
    option: _innerOptions
  })), acc;
}, []);

// Generate the output by cloning the input object, removing its `option` property, and assigning the calculated option_group property.
// I've also put maxQty, but I'm pretty sure you should give further explanations on how to calculate it, just change it as you need.
const output = Object.assign({}, input, {
  quantity_max: maxQty,
  option_group: _groupedOptions
});
delete output.option;
console.log(output);
```